# Custom Listview not responding to listener after activity destroyed

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a BaseActivity that takes care of Fragment transitions by acting as the central controller for it's Fragment's touch listeners. One of the Fragment is a custom Listview that will cause the BaseActivity to display a new Fragment when tapped. This works when the Activity is created from scratch, but I have a problem with it when the activity is destroyed (through the Dev options "Don't Keep Activities", or through memory cleanup).

I have verified through logs that I am setting the Fragment's listener when the activity starts up from being destroyed, but tapping on the Listview doesn't transition to a new Fragment. I also tried to see if it was a focusing issue but putting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the Listview layout xml also doesn't solve the issue.

The listener is set when I create the fragment and it is the first fragment the activity instantiates when it starts up. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you setting the fragment listener? `onCreateView` ?

Comment: Fragment listeners are set onCreateView, yes. The Fragment Listview OnitemClickListener calls the implemented listener that the BaseActivity sets when creating the fragment.

Comment: I've answered to be easier to read, maybe we can work on from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add a answer to be easier to help you. The first thing is that you listener should be set inside fragment's `onAttach`:

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    // here, your context is also your activity
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof YourListener) {
        this.fragmentListener = (YourListener) context;
    }
}
```

Please change this and check if something changed!

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't understand the difference between setting the Listener when I create the Fragment vs. setting it onAttach. If my app is garbage collected, it must go through the fragment creation to re-instantiate the fragment correct?

Comment: The lifecycle changes when you have "Don't keep activies" on, and also is the recommended way to assign your listener inside `onAttach`. Here's the reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html .
Also check this about different lifecycles http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/fragment-lifecycle-with-respect-to-its.html . Hope it helps! :)